# Read stream till the line reaches a certain character

Tags: c#

I am trying to read stream of data using the below code. The loop should only come out if the stream contains "[w" as the starting characters or else should 
continue reading the data. How to check if the starting characters of the stream is "[w" in the below code

```
private StringBuilder ReadStream(StreamReader reader)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.Clear();
            result.Length = 0;
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                result.AppendLine(line);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe using `String.StartsWith(...)`?

Comment: In while loop add if(line.Contains("]w") break;

Comment: You can try to use `StreamReader.Read()` method

Comment: Title and description contain 2 different problems and requests, please be clear.

Comment: @jdweng Your bracket is facing the wrong direction. Also OP is only wanting to break out of the loop if the line starts with "[w", not if it's just in the line somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(line.StartsWith("[w")) 
    {
        break; //Or do something
    }
    result.AppendLine(line);
}
```